# AWS API Gateway HTTP APIs CORS issue when use ANY method

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have trouble when use ANY method in API Gateway HTTP APIs routes setting but after I changed HTTP Method to PATCH it's working fine.

Why is that? Isn't ANY method should work with all HTTP Verbs?

Comment: "I have trouble " - is not specific. What exactly is the issue? Any code examples, any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

The browser will check the CORS headers at your URL by sending an OPTIONS request.

If your route doesn't support the OPTIONS method, then API Gateway will implement it for you.

If your route says ANY method, then you have to implement OPTIONS yourself.  You probably just haven't implemented this properly.  Note that it can be quite difficult, because that OPTIONS request will not be sent with any authentication headers, etc., so you can't use the built-in authorizers.

Usually it's best just to make explicit routes for the methods you support and let AWS handle OPTIONS.

Comment: I think this is relevant part of [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html) for that.

Comment: I'm speaking specifically about HTTP APIs.  Those docs are for REST APIs, and a similar problem might exist there, too, but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS

Go to API Gateway -> Select your API endpoint -> Select the method ->click dropdown ACTIONS > Enable CORS

Redeploy API

[image]

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cors-errors/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html

Comment: Your second link is for HTTP API, but your description for REST API.