# AWS REST API throws CORS error when invoked from browser works in postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I configured a REST API in API gateway. It calls a lambda function to return rows. When I tested the API in the AWS console, it works fine. When invoked from the app it throws the following error.
[image: consoleError]

I copied the request as cURL command from the browser and tested from postman, and I see the response in postman. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html have you tried this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67013908/aws-api-gateway-http-apis-cors-issue-when-use-any-method/67014117#67014117

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about taking this error too literally. What often happens is that there is a underlying error in the API and it responded with an error message only, and thereby did not send any course headers. So it's not really a course header issue but instead some other error. Check with curl directly and see what's responding with.